# Como atualizar site ASP.NET hospedado na Locaweb

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

Tenho um site rodando há 4 anos em um cliente meu. O site foi desenvolvido em VB.Net, e a Locaweb fez a migração dos servidores dela de Windows 2003 para o 2008 e por consequência mudou o *Trust Level* de *Full* para *Medium* e apareceu o seguinte erro no site que não sei como resolver.

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Como eu devo fazer para atualizar este componente para ele funcionar em Medium Trust? Lembrando que a Locaweb não me permite alterar o nível do *Trust* via `web.config`. Obrigado.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505770/how-to-disable-system-security-permissions-reflectionpermission-usage-in-new-vs2 Olhe se pode te ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi olha a sugestão deste post é para eu alterar via web.config o Trust Level para Full. E é o que exatamente a meleca da Locaweb não me permite fazer. Quando eu tento isto me da o seguinte erro: `This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.`. Se tiver outra sugestão agradeço.

Comment: Joao achei isso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock

Comment: A resposta do suporte da LocaWeb foi que eles abriram uma exceção e eu tenho 10 dias para alterar. Pelo jeito o AspEmail não vai funcionar mais mas não me responderam quais componentes funcionarão. Estou migrando para system.net.mail. Tem exemplo na página deles mesmo em http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Envio_de_e-mails_via_.NET_utilizando_o_System.Net.Mail.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque se trata de peculiaridade da hospedagem contratada e foi resolvida pelo suporte da respectiva empresa, além do que a questão não teve atividade depois disso (usuários com o mesmo problema precisariam se dirigir ao suporte da empresa, de qualquer forma).